# Selecting rows from multiple tables. How?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say that we have tree tables.

```
Products                  Fields                Fields Value
----------------          -------------         --------------
  pid    catid             fid   catid            fid   pid   value
-------|-------|          -----|-------         ------|-----|--------
   1       1                1      1               1     1     25%
   2       1                2      1               1     2     32.5%
                            3      2               2     1     45%
                                                   2     2     42%
                                                   3     1     17.3%
                                                   3     2     21%
```

The normal way is selecting `Products` in a one query and loop through result set(`RS1`).
Then we select `Fields` for `catid` per each row (`RS2`). 
Then doing the same action with `RS2` for selecting `Fields Value'.

Only problem is performance issue that will be reduced due to **executing a lot of queries**` when there are a lot of rows in each table.

Would you suggest me better solution to execute **less queries** ?

**edit**
I want to show each product in a box and show fields for each product with it's proper value. joining tree tables together will returns duplicated values for each `FieldValue` in `Products` and not usable in loop.

Comment: use a single query with join(s) ?

Comment: You want a `JOIN`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: less queries but more complicated :)

Comment: You can also create a `VIEW` containing the `JOIN` and some redundant data covering all possible options, which you can query from your code to obtain the correct record.

Answer (score 2):

Guessing what you need, try this:

```
SELECT f.catid, fv.* FROM Fields f
INNER JOIN Products p 
  ON f.catid = p.catid
INNER JOIN FieldsValue fv
  ON fv.fid = f.fid AND fv.pid = p.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Products
       NATURAL JOIN Fields
       NATURAL JOIN FieldsValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

use Join Syntax :

```
SELECT * FROM Products as P
LEFT JOIN FieldsValue as FV ON FV.PID = P.PID
LEFT JOIN Fields as F on F.fid = FV.fid
```

Comment: Why LEFT OUTER JOIN?  Why not INNER JOIN?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Why not NATURAL JOIN? Why not product with restriction? Why so many choices?!

Comment: The important thing is that it misses the join condition on `catid`

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables together using `left join`:

```
select *
from Products p
left join Fields f on f.catid = p.catid
left join `fields value` fv on fv.fid = f.fid on fv.pid = p.pid
where p.pid = 1
```

Comment: You also need `fv.pid = p.pid`